# Opened an existing Ionic project in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ionic-framework, apache-cordova

I was wondering if someone has already develop any project in Ionic and it is gonna use for now on Visual Studio Community. I am trying to open the ionic project in Visual Studio but It didn't recognize.

There is someone that has the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: Create a new blank Ionic project in Visual Studio and then copy your existing project in.**

The file structure for an Ionic project created using in Visual Studio is almost identical to a traditional Ionic project.

The only differences are that Visual Studio also creates a few additional Visual Studio specific files in a addition to all the standard Ionic ones: `ProjectName.sln`, `ProjectName.jsproj`, `ProjectName.jsproj.user`, `taco.json`

If your existing project was created outside of Visual Studio, you could always create a new blank Ionic project in Visual Studio* and then copy your existing project in.  Having done this, opening the `ProjectName.sln` file with Visual Studio will open up your Ionic project.

* [A helpful introduction to creating ionic projects in visual studio can be found here.](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was trying to copy all the folders in a new blank Ionic proyect in Visual Studio. But There is a mistake, it said something like there is not apache cordova file.